# How do I parse ndjson file using Golang?

Tags: go, ndjson

I have a `ndjson` (newline delimited JSON) file, I need to parse it and get the data for some logical operation. Is there any good method for parsing `ndjson` files using golang. A sample ndjson is given below

```
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":[{"d":"100","e":"10"}]}
{"a":"2","b":"2","c":[{"d":"101","e":"11"}]}
{"a":"3","b":"2","c":[{"d":"102","e":"12"}]}
```

Comment: Some time ago I wrote this: https://github.com/bserdar/jsonstream

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The encoding/json [Decoder](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder) parses sequential JSON documents with optional or required whitespace depending on the value type. Because newlines are whitespace, the decoder handles `ndjson`.

```
d := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(stream))
for {
    // Decode one JSON document.
    var v interface{}
    err := d.Decode(&v)

    if err != nil {
        // io.EOF is expected at end of stream.
        if err != io.EOF {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        break
    }

    // Do something with the value.
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/na-PSNvaKla).

Comment: FTR: Decoder doesn't require any kind of separation between documents: https://play.golang.org/p/oHc5xaegQuC.

Comment: @Peter I updated answer regarding whitespace.  Separation is required for some value types: https://play.golang.org/p/ztaeA5UYKlo